# SQL Server Management Studio : precision errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

```
select 10/2
```

Output : 5

```
Select 2/10
```

Output : 0

```
Select Convert(numeric(2,2),2/10)
```

Output : 0.00

```
Select 10*(Convert(numeric(2,2),2/10))
```

Output : 0.00

```
Select 10*(2/10)
```

Output : 0

Why is the output flawed ?

Are the arithmetic function (Divide) working ?

Comment: It's not ***flawed*** - it's doing **exactly** what's documented - you're using **integer division** and `2 / 10` in integer division **is** 0 - no matter what output type you define (this is applied only *after* the operation)....

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea about integer division here. Now it seems perfectly fine to me. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide `int` and `int` you get `int`. For this reason you need to divide `int` and `float`, hence `select 10/2.0`.

When you convert to `numeric` you convert result - so you receive `0.00`.

For this reason `2/10` result `0`. You must convert before division or add decimal part like `.0`

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443672/integer-division-in-sql-server).