# Teradata keeps returning zeros for decimals

Tags: sql, decimal, teradata

Casting as decimal with precision 2, keeps returning 00 after the decimal. How do I actually return values?

column1   hourlycolumn1

----------   ------------------

9797       163.00

358         5.00

265         4.00

```
    select top 10

column1,cast(column1/60 as decimal(6,2)) as "hourlycolumn1"

from 

....
```

What I would like to return is below

column1   hourlycolumn1

----------   ------------------

9797       163.28

358         5.96

265         4.41

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443672/integer-division-in-sql-server try converting your column1 to decimal as well

Comment: The fix that involves the minimal amount of typing is to change 60 to a decimal value such as 60.0

Answer (score 4):

Your column is an Integer and Integer-division truncates. The cast to decimal is *after* truncation.

Simply cast before division

```
column1,cast(column1 as decimal(6,2))/60
```

Calculations based on Decimals are a bit tricky in Teradata because it's rounded after every step, thus a basic recommendation is to to multiplication before division. See [DECIMAL Result Data Type](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_151K/decimal_result_data_type_BINARY_ARITHMETIC_RESULT_DATA_TYPES.html#ww3_10_7_10_1)