# Teradata: Average of date difference truncates decimal

Tags: sql, decimal, teradata

**Teradata**: I have `Start_Timestamp` and `End_Timestamp` and I need to find the average `Avg_Duration` for every `ID`.

Dataset looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|ID     | Start_Timestamp             |End_Timestamp               |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|111    |2021-08-25 19:37:51.327000   |2021-08-26 16:25:51.129600  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|111    |2021-07-16 06:17:23.124000   |2021-07-19 13:16:53.185350  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|111    |2021-06-22 10:11:21.754400   |2021-02-25 18:48:13.614650  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I ran the following code:

```
SELECT ID, AVG((End_Timestamp - Start_Timestamp) DAY ) AS Avg_Duration
FROM Table_A
Group By ID;
```

The result looks like this:

```
-----------------------
|ID     | Aug_Duration|
-----------------------
|111    |            2|
-----------------------
```

I expected `Avg_Duration` to be `(1+3+3)/3=2.33`.

I am aware that [`integer division`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734036/teradata-keeps-returning-zeros-for-decimals) gets truncated. So, I `CAST` the Timestamp difference before I took average to convert Integer into Decimal. My code for that is:

```
SELECT ID, AVG(CAST((End_Timestamp - Start_Timestamp) DAY AS DECIMAL(2,2))) AS Avg_Duration
FROM Table_A
Group By ID;
```

I expected `2.33`, but, now TeraData window is unresponsive/idle. It neither runs nor I get any error message.

Can someone tell me where am I making a mistake and how can I get `Avg_Duration` with 2 decimal places and not a truncated one?

Comment: `decimal(2.2)` is the wrong data type, both digits are fractional. But this should result in an *overflow* error message.  Are you sure it actually executes, can you find it in the history? `AVG(CAST((End_Timestamp - Start_Timestamp DAY(4)) AS DECIMAL(6,2)))` should work

Comment: Sorry, das war ein Tippfehler.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It seems to work. I have a question -  Why we do `DAY (4)`? What does 4 mean here? (`DAY AS DECIMAL(6,2)` idea I got from your old answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734036/teradata-keeps-returning-zeros-for-decimals

Comment: The default precision for DAY is 2, switching to the maximum prevents overflow error (of course, you still get one if it's over 9999 days)

Comment: Btw, you can also get your expected result using `Avg(Cast(End_Timestamp AS DATE) - Cast(Start_Timestamp AS DATE))`, which will not run in any overflow

Comment: Thank you so much. This snippet of code works too. Now I understand that simple subtracting was not working because it was a timestamp and not a date. Could you kindly, put these two snippetrs of code in Answer, so that I can accept them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a `)` in the wrong place. But I doubt it caused an issue on Teradata, probably you just didn't notice that the client (Studio?) simply didn't submit it as it was invalid.

This works as expected - after changing `DEC(2,2)` (two significant digits) to `DEC(6,2)`(6 significant digits) to avoid an overflow error:

```
AVG(CAST((End_Timestamp - Start_Timestamp DAY(4)) AS DECIMAL(6,2)))
```

Even with the maximum DAY(4) you might still get an *Interval Overflow* error, but your logic can also be calculated using dates:

```
Avg(Cast(End_Timestamp AS DATE) - Cast(Start_Timestamp AS DATE))
```

Finally, as it's based on Timestamps you might want more detailed Intervals like

```
Avg(End_Timestamp - Start_Timestamp DAY(4) TO SECOND(0))
Avg(End_Timestamp - Start_Timestamp DAY(4) TO MINUTE)
```