# Calculate moving average with null values

Tags: sql, t-sql, null, moving-average, divide-by-zero

I have a school graduation data set by year and subgroup and have been provided the numerator and denominator and the single year graduation rate but I also need to calculate a 3 year moving average.  I was advised by a statistician that no longer works with us that to do this I needed to get the running total for the numerator for 3 years and the running total for 3 years for the denominator. I understand the math behind it and have checked my work by hand and via excel with a few subgroups. I have also calculated this using T-SQL with no problem so long as there are no null records but I’m struggling with the calculation when there are nulls or 0.

I have tried running the query accounting for null by using NULLIF

```
   ID,
   Bldg,
   GradClass,
   Sbgrp ,
   TGrads,
   TStus,
   Rate,
/*Numerator Running total*/
   SUM (TGrads) OVER ( partition BY ID, Sbgrp ORDER BY GradClass ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND CURRENT row ) AS NumSum,
/*Denominator Running Total*/
   SUM ( TStus) OVER ( partition BY ID, Sbgrp ORDER BY GradClass ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND CURRENT row ) AS DenSum,
/*Moving Year Average*/
   (
       ( SUM ( TGrads) OVER ( partition BY DistrictID, Sbgrp ORDER BY GradClass ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND CURRENT row ) ) / NULLIF ( ( SUM ( TStus) OVER ( partition BY ID, Sbgrp ORDER BY GradClass ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND CURRENT row ) ), 0 ) * 100 
   ) AS 3yrAvg 
FROM
   KResults.DGSRGradBldg
```

First question, I was provided a record for all subgroups even if they didn’t have students in the subgroup. I want to keep the record so that all subgroups are accounted for within the district and since I know that they didn’t have data, can I substitute the Null values in Tgrads, TStus with a 0? If I do substitute those values with a 0 how can I show the rate as null?

Second question how can I compute the rate with either a null or 0 denominator? I understand you can’t divide by 0 but I want to maintain the record so it’s easy and clear to see that they had no data. How can I do this? When I try to calculate this without accounting for Null I get errors, 1.)Divide by zero error encountered. (8134) and 2.) Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation. (8153).

Knowing I can’t divide by 0 or Null I modified my query to include NULLIF and when I do that the query runs with no errors but I don’t get accurate percentage for rates that are below 100%. All my rates are now either 100% or 0 - note the last row, the moving average of 2/3 is not 0.

Here’s what the data looks like if I try to account for nulls my Moving three year average shows as 0. Note the Moving three year Avg Column shows all 0.

```
ID   Bldg    Class   Sbggrp  TGrads  TStus      Rate    NumSum DenSum  3yrAvg  
A    1      2014       A1    46      49         93.9    46     49       0
A    1      2015       A1    41      46         89.1    87     95       0
A    1      2016       A1    47      49         95.9    134    144      0
A    1      2017       A1    38      40         95.0    126    135      0
A    1      2018       A1    59      59         98.3    143    148      0
A    1      2014       A2    1       1          100     1      1        100
A    1      2015       A2                               1      1        100
A    1      2016       A2                               1      1        100
A    1      2017       A2    2       3          66.7    2      3        0
A    1      2018       A2    2       2          100     4      5        0
```

Any advice would be appreciated but please provide suggestions kindly to this newbie. 
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are actually asking.  Perhaps you could ask another question that is a bit simpler.

Comment: Its unclear to me as well.  Appears that 3yrAvg NULLIF is resulting in only in 1 or 0 and then multiplying by 100 to generate results.

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification. I need to get the 3 year rate but if there are null records than my rate returns an error b/c it's dividing by null. So how can I get the rate if I have null records? I can't exclude the null records b/c folks I'm working for want to see all records regardless. I'm only trying to multiply at the end to get a percent. Forget the 3 year rate if it's easier - how can I take one column and divide by another and not throw an error if there are nulls? My current method isn't providing the results I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 1: put in the select condition

```
ISNULL(TGrads,0) AS TGRADS,
ISNULL(TStus,0) AS TSTUS,
```

Answer to question 2: I'd do this

```
(CASE WHEN SUM(TStus) OVER ( partition BY ID, Sbgrp ORDER BY GradClass ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND CURRENT row ) IS NOT NULL
AND SUM(TStus) OVER ( partition BY ID, Sbgrp ORDER BY GradClass ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND CURRENT row ) <>0
THEN (SUM(TGrads) OVER ( partition BY DistrictID, Sbgrp ORDER BY GradClass ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND CURRENT row )  / (SUM(TStus) OVER ( partition BY ID, Sbgrp ORDER BY GradClass ROWS BETWEEN 2 preceding AND CURRENT row ) ) ) * 100
ELSE NULL END
   ) AS 3yrAvg
```

I put null after "ELSE"...You can choose your default value.

Comment: Thanks for the help as your answer to number 1 worked well but answer to number 2 still doesn't produce the correct percents. For example if the running numerator is 3 and the running denominator is 3, than the moving average is 100% and that's accurate but when the percent is anything other than 100% it produces 0, such as 46/49 the percent shows as 0. How can I get the moving average of 46/49 as an example to = 93.87 instead of 0?

Comment: the problem could be that both numerator and denominator are integers. Try to look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443672/integer-division-in-sql-server

Comment: ```@Gufus```I think you were spot on. The fields were stored as integer. When setting to float the math works. Is there a way to set the precision and scale on float division? I'd like only 2 digits behind the decimal and I'm getting 13. Also, is there any reason why this query would run so slow (41 seconds) with only 34000 records?

Comment: I'm not an expert in choosing the best numeric format, but reading this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056323/difference-between-numeric-float-and-decimal-in-sql-server I think you should use decimal (decimal(9,2) seems good!). I hope it helps to get the query faster, but even for few records you can have slow queries expecially if you use order by conditions. Have you tried to use a temporary table? Maybe it gives some benefits...