# Divide by Case When

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently doing some work on a 6 month rolling report, but i seem to be a little bit stuck on one area.

I have one column Liveatcutoff_PC it will be populated by 1 for live or 0 for not live. If it's 0 it means it's cancelled. I want to work out the cancellation % for the date range in my code but I'm not having much luck.

```
SELECT 

UserID
,Agent
,COUNT(CASE WHEN SaleDate>=DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-6, 0)
    AND SaleDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())-6, 0)
    AND LiveAtCutOff_PC='0' THEN LiveAtCutOff_PC END)

FROM PDS_SALES_PMI

WHERE SaleDate>='2019-01-01'
AND Leaver='0'
GROUP BY UserID, Agent
```

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Sample data and desired output would make this clear.

Comment: So you want to find out what is the percentage of canceled sales in your table for the 6 month period?

Comment: Just for the month 6 months ago, but that month will move due to the date range.

Comment: And you want to group by AgentID and UserID. so you need percentage of canceled sales per agentID per userID?

Comment: What is all that -6 date math supposed to be doing for the end of the range?

Comment: @Shawnt00 it references the last day of the month in the start date.

Comment: Yes, it is strictly less than. Wouldn't it make more sense to use the same expression as the first but with -5?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `AVG()`:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN SaleDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-6, 0) AND
              SaleDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())-6, 0)       THEN LiveAtCutOff_PC * 1.0
    END) as LiveAtCutoff_PC_ratio
```

Your question specifies that `LiveAtCutOff_PC` has values of `0` and `1`, which implies that the field is a number.  However, the code compares it to a string, which suggests otherwise.  If the values are only `0` and `1` then the above should work for both numbers and strings (although for `bit` you would need to convert the value).

Comment: Unless those numbers are integers, in which case it won't work, e.g. `WITH x AS (SELECT 0 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1) SELECT AVG(x) FROM x;` returns 0, because 0 and 1 are both integers.  To get a decimal answer you would need something like `WITH x AS (SELECT 0.0 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1) SELECT AVG(x) FROM x;`

Comment: @RichardHansell . . . I adjusted the answer to take that into account.

Comment: Cool, I missed the `* 1.0` as it was off the side of the query!

Comment: @gordonLinoff, Thank you for the reply - I think this goes some way towards solving this. However, The cancellation % does need to go against total policies solid and I'm not sure this calculates this correctly based on the results.

Answer (score 0):

So since you requirement is to find out the percentage of canceled sales then you don't have to do it in one query. Case will just calculate everything, including nulls(that will come up because you don't have 'else') 
you might want to try subquery instead or use CTE.

CTE example

```
with CTE as (
Select  UserID
       ,Agent
       ,COUNT(*) as Canceled
from PDS_SALES_PMI
where   SaleDate >=DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-6, 0)
    AND SaleDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())-6, 0)
    AND LiveAtCutOff_PC='0'
    AND SaleDate >='2019-01-01'
    AND Leaver = 0
group by UserID, AgentID)

Select a.UserID
      ,a.AgentID
      ,Canceled/COUNT(*) * 100.0 as Canceled_Percent
From PDS_SALES_PMI a INNER JOIN CTE 
on  a.AgentID = CTE.AgentID
and a.UserID  = CTE.UserID
Where SaleDate >=DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-6, 0)
  AND SaleDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())-6, 0)
  AND SaleDate >='2019-01-01'
  AND Leaver = 0
Group by a.UserID, a.AgentID
```

Subquery Example

```
Select a.UserID
          ,a.AgentID
          ,Canceled/COUNT(*) * 100.0 as Canceled_Percent
    From PDS_SALES_PMI a INNER JOIN (
                   Select  UserID
                          ,Agent
                          ,COUNT(*) as Canceled
                   from PDS_SALES_PMI
                   where SaleDate >=DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,GETDATE())-6, 0)
                     AND SaleDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())-6, 0)
                     AND LiveAtCutOff_PC='0'
                     AND SaleDate >='2019-01-01'
                     AND Leaver = 0
                   group by UserID, AgentID) as Tmp
    on  a.AgentID = Tmp.AgentID
    and a.UserID  = Tmp.UserID
    Where SaleDate >=DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-6, 0)
      AND SaleDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -6, GETDATE())-6, 0)
      AND SaleDate >='2019-01-01'
      AND Leaver = 0
    Group by a.UserID, a.AgentID
```

Comment: ...and this has the same problem with integer division.  It's easy to fix, just change `100` to `100.0` for example.

Comment: @RichardHansell I don't see the problem with *100. If you get 2/10= 0.2. 0.2 *100 = 20

Comment: integer math.  2/10 will not equal 0.2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443672/integer-division-in-sql-server

Comment: @RichardHansell Thank you, didn't know about that, added to the answer