# SQL Mathematical operator between queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wondering what the best method would be of using two separate query results in a mathematical operation.

```
select count(*) as french_films
from language l 
join film f on l.language_id = f.original_language_id
where l.name = 'French'
group by l.name

select count(*) as non_english_films
from language l 
join film f on l.language_id = f.original_language_id
where l.name != 'English'
```

The code itself produces a result of **12** for the first query and **59** for the second query.

I want to express the 1st number (12) as a percentage of the 2nd (59) which should be around **20.34%.**

I've attempted this as 2 separate CTEs however am struggling on what is best to join them on or if that is the best method.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when l.name = 'French' then 1 else 0 end) as french_films,
       sum(case when l.name <> 'English' then 1 else 0 end) as non_english_films
from language l join
     film f
     on l.language_id = f.original_language_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Small follow up if you can help. It isn't my database and the data type is set to INT as it would always be a whole number of films. My issue is that when i attempt to do:


SELECT ((french_films/non_english_films)*100)
FROM
(AGGREGATION ABOVE) T1

It is returning zero, any suggestions?

Comment: SQL Server performs integer division for integer types.  See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443672/integer-division-in-sql-server

Comment: That's perfect!
Thank you both for your help :)