# SQL Count and getting percentage

Tags: sql, count, percentage

Would like to ask for help with this SQL problem i have.
The goal is to get the total percentage of how many 1 are in the column

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4zFG.png)

im planning to get the percentage of the dispute lost using count.
Here is the code that i used

```
SELECT ((
    SELECT count (dispute_lost) 
    FROM yellevate_data_2 
    WHERE dispute_lost =1)) AS Dispute_count,
    (count(dispute_lost)) AS Total_Dispute_count ,
    (((SELECT count (dispute_lost) 
    FROM yellevate_data_2 
    WHERE dispute_lost =1))/(
    count(dispute_lost)))*100 AS mult
    
FROM yellevate_data_2;
```

and here are the results

[image: Result]

the mult column should show 4.09 but it only displays 0

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: You're stumbling on an integer division problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443672/integer-division-in-sql-server